# Overlay RegionPlots

Tags: plotting

I wish to generate the following graphic:

[image]

The code I have come up with is

```
Show[
  RegionPlot[0 <= y <= 1 - x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[0.8], BoundaryStyle -> Black, 
    Frame -> False, Axes -> True],
 RegionPlot[0 <= y <= 1 - x, {x, 0.4, 0.45}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[0.4], BoundaryStyle -> None, Frame -> False, 
  Axes -> True],
 Plot[{1 - x, 0}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {{Black}}]
]
```

The basic problem I had was that after overlaying the first region plot with the second, the portion of the (black) boundaries of the region in the area where the darker band was drawn were overdrawn by the dark band, thus the need for the repetitive `Plot` to redraw the boundaries.

I tried various `BoundaryStyle` directives in the second `RegionPlot`, including `BoundaryStyle->Directive[Thick,Opacity[0]]`, to no avail.

Is there a better way than what I'm doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put everything in a single `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[{0 <= y <= 1 - x, ConditionalExpression[0 <= y <= 1 - x, 0.4 <= x <= 0.45]}, 
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8], GrayLevel[0.2]}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> Directive[Thick, Black], 2 -> None}, 
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

If you just need to have thick `1-x` line, you can use `MeshFunctions` :

```
RegionPlot[{0 <= y <= 1 - x, ConditionalExpression[0 <= y <= 1 - x, 0.4 <= x <= 0.45]}, 
 {x, 0,  1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8], GrayLevel[0.2]}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {1 - # - #2 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Black]}}}, 
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! A couple of questions: first, the boundaries on the axis weren't drawn. I've tried messing around with the `MeshFunctions` (adding `#&` and `#2&`) but have not been able to understand the documentation well enough, since I can't get those lines drawn. Second question: although the `ConditionalExpression` in your answer works, it does give a warning `ImplicitRegion`.

Comment: @rogerl,  i am using version 9.0.1 (windows 10) and don't get any warning messages. Re boundaries on the axes, please see the updated version.